# UIButton's addtarget: not called after touch it!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have the following code, and when i press the UIButton, nothing is called, and it doesn't crash.

```
    calloutButton = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(left_width2*2-3, 5, 230, 230)];
    UIButton *buttongo= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    buttongo.frame=CGRectMake(0, -1, 25, 25);
    [buttongo addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [calloutButton addSubview:buttongo];

    [label addSubview:calloutButton];




    -(IBAction)buttonEvent:(id)sender 
    {
          NSLog(@"Hello...");
    }
```

Someone Knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the size of the label, it can be CGSizeZero, but because the clipping of subviews is NO by default so the button is visible, but it isn't touchable.

Comment: i have the following. I think is what you mean.

label=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((-left_width2*2+21)/2)-21, 19 - ANCHOR_Y, 100, CALLOUT_HEIGHT)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

The Brown Color is behind the label

Comment: then please test if the UILabel's userInteractionEnabled is YES. Also, why do you add a button to a label?

Comment: whats left_width and other variables, either print all the exact values for cgrect or tell the variable values.

Comment: Yes, Filthy Night has right, maybe the button is outside of the label's frame. You should check the frame too.

Comment: Thanks, it was a userInteractionEnabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you not have

```
@property IBOutlet UIButton *yourButton;
```

with same name with

```
@implementation {
    UIButton *_yourButton;
}
```

I had such problem