# UIButton Action Not Called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton that I'm adding dynamically using content parsed from an XML file (it's also getting cached).

The first time I run the app, the button's action isn't getting called - but its image and everything else loads just fine. The second time I run the app, the button works.

Any clue on why the button's action doesn't get called the first time I run the app?

```
- (void)fetchHeader
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    // Initiate the request...

    channel1 = [[FeedStore sharedStore] fetchFeaturedHeaderWithCompletion:
            ^(RSSChannel *obj, NSError *err) {

                if(!err) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

                    // Set our channel to the merged one
                    channel1 = obj;

                    RSSItem *d = [[channel1 items] objectAtIndex:0];
                    RSSItem *c = [[channel1 items] objectAtIndex:1];


                    NSString *param = [d photoURL]; // the URL from the XML
                    NSString *param1 = [c photoURL]; // the URL from the XML


                    featured1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
                    [featured1 addTarget:self action:@selector(featuredButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    [featured1 setFrame:CGRectMake(18, 20, 123, 69)];
                    [featured1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:param] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"featuredheaderbg.png"]];
                    featured1.tag = 1;
                    [[self view] addSubview:featured1];
                }
       }];
}
```

Comment: When you step through in the debugger, does anything different happen between first and subsequent launches?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908879/uibuttons-addtarget-not-called-after-touch-it?rq=1 and also add userEnteractionEnabled to TRUE

Comment: Check that no other view is covering the button. Even hidden views on top of the button would prevent it from receiving your events.

Comment: Please share the body of function **setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible** in your question

Comment: Vimal, that's a standard UIKit function - it adds the little spinner to the UIStatusBar.

Comment: Resh32, turns out a view was covering the button on first load of the content. No idea why it only happened the first time, but I got it fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that a UIView was covering up the button below it. Because the view was transparent, I didn't realize it was covering anything up.